# difference between 歩く and 散歩します

Tags: translation

I was wondering the difference between the two words since both mean to walk.

When to use verb 歩きます and when to use 散歩します。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The verb 散歩する is equivalent to the English term "take a walk". That is, 散歩 is more of a recreational activity, as opposed to it simply being a means to get from one place to another. 歩く is a general term for walking.

From [dictionary.goo.co.jp](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/92043/m0u/):

> 気晴らしや健康などのために、ぶらぶら歩くこと。散策。「公園を―する」
> To leisurely walk for recreation or for health. A stroll. "*_* through the park"

Answer (score 2):

The 散 of 散歩 is also a clue as to how it's different:

```
散る・散らす
散らかる・散らかす
⇒　ばらばらになる・する　⇒　ぶらぶら（と）歩く　≒　当てもなく歩く
```